# Silent install of .NET 4.0 on Windows Embedded Standard 7

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework, windows-embedded-7, .net-4.0

I want to perform a silent install of the .NET 4.0 framework on a Windows Embedded Standard 7 installation. This means I want to use the Image Configuration Editor (ICE) to perform this. I already downladed the templates to solve all the dependencies. I think the .NET 4.0 installation is failing because of the lack of Administrator rights. I added three commands to `Deployment_x86` in my answer file:

- `net user administrator /active:yes`
- `C:\Setup_Files\dotNetFx40_Full_x86_x64.exe`
- `net user administrator /active:no`

Everything on pass 6: Audit User. For now it does not work. What would be the needed steps to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Rights problems during installation can not be. Performing during the installation of the operating system occurs with the rights `SYSTEM`.

Accordingly, the command `net user administrator /active ...` not need.

You will need the templates that can be taken here:

[Application templates on Windows Embedded Standard 7](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/catcatalog.aspx)

I think it's not quite the distribution. Net 4, which is needed.

Try to get hold of this one:

[Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 for Windows Embedded Standard 7 (Dec 2010)](http://www.mdspacific.com/wecom/resourceView.asp?page=2&s_type=title&s_value=&s_gubun=os&s_os=&s_pds=N&idx=954)

may be help ...

Comment: Instead of a non working link to a Chinese (?) page, here it is to Microsoft page (as far as I can find): https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/Download/confirmation.aspx?id=17718